Intra Schengen passport check non EU Wizzair 2024
Do Wizzair still have extra passport check for non EU citizens flying in the Schengen area?
I remember flying with Ryanair and other airlines. They would ask my travel information on check in (online). With Ryanair I needed to have my passport checked to collect a printed boarding pass in their airport desk before the flight. With other airlines I just submit my information online and my passport is checked at the gate.
I'm traveling tomorrow with Wizzair and they already issued my boarding pass. However, they didn't ask any extra information on check in (only my full name).
Is this how everybody travels in the Schengen area now or is Wizzair going to deny my boarding at the gate due to a little known rule?
As far as I can tell they don't know if I'm a EU citizen or not.

This Wizzair check in and boarding page says “if you hold non-EU travel documents, you need to present yourself at the check-in counter to have your documentation checked and your boarding card stamped”.

Thanks for the info. Do you know how it works if you check in the app? "Mobile app
use mobile boarding pass
instead of a boarding card". I used the app and I can only see my boarding pass on the app, there's no option to have a printable PDF. Should I print a screenshot?

Dis you have some particular class of "little known rule" in mind?  It seems like you must be concerned about rules relating to ID documents and passports, but it's hard for me to imagine what that might be and how it would be less likely to be a problem if you had entered the information into their system already.

@Traveller I just noticed, on the page you linked to, "if you are travelling within the Schengen area you don’t need to fill in the travel document details during the online check-in procedure, since you are not required to provide such details." -- did you overlook it?  I did in the first three or four readings.  Somehow, putting information in a box with different colors causes me to pay less attention rather than  more,

@phoog I did notice that but I found it confusing and I wasn’t sure how the two instructions tie up, since the latter only refers to online check in and there’s no explicit ‘if you’re travelling within the Schengen area your documents will be checked at (wherever they’re checked) or similar.


However, they didn't ask any extra information on check in (only my full name).

Regardless of whether they have the details of your identity document in their system, they will probably require you to show that your name matches the boarding pass, which means showing the document at boarding.

Is this how everybody travels in the Schengen area now

No.  You generally have to identify yourself.  Some airlines may look at non-EU citizens' visa status, but most don't.

or is Wizzair going to deny my boarding at the gate due to a little known rule?

This is always possible, but they certainly won't deny boarding because they don't have some piece of information that they failed to ask for.  At least, if they did attempt such a nonsensical thing, you would have a right to compensation for improperly denied boarding.

As far as I can tell they don't know if I'm a EU citizen or not.

As far as I can tell this only matters if the airline's own rules treat EU citizens differently.
Finally, did you check in through the website or through the mobile app?  If you checked in through the website, you need to bring a printed copy of the boarding pass and, as Traveller notes in the comments, you are instructed to take it to the counter for  a document check if you have non-EU documents.  If you have EU documents, presumably they will look at them when they scan your boarding pass at the gate.  There is no indication of how this works with mobile check-in.  They explicitly say that no printing is needed.  I suppose that the process includes uploading an image of your identification document.  Even so, they will probably want to see it at boarding to make sure that you are in fact the person who is named on the ticket.
Also note that the site says

If you are travelling within the Schengen area you don’t need to fill in the travel document details during the online check-in procedure, since you are not required to provide such details.

It's possible if not likely that non-EU travelers aren't required to show their documents at the counter and that the inconsistency is due to a hasty edit.
Regardless, as is always the case with air travel, you should be prepared to show your documents whenever asked, expect to show them on boarding, and let the airline worry about when or whether it needs to record the details and pass them to the authorities.

I think Phoog have a great general answer. However, after my experience with Ryanair and today's experience I believe this detail depends on the airport and also a bit on the discretion of the boarding agent.
From what I can read online some people are denied boarding because the gate agent is not able to verify that their travel documents are valid for the destination. This is rather counter intuitive, because the Schengen area has almost no boarder checks within itself and citizens can move freely with a national ID.
This check can be made in a number of different ways, on a separate airport desk, on the check in desk (that's the official writting of Ryanair and Wizzair, but I'm yet to see that), or at the gate. It seems that non budget airlines do it on check in at the airport or online and in the later case the passenger might not even notice it.
Today I was at the airport rather early and couldn't find any Wizzair representative. I went through security and ask someone working there, who seems to also operate boarding gates and he told me this check can be made at the gate. I'm already passed the boarding gate and I'm unsure if the agent just waved me through like the EU citizens or if he was also seeing some visa information on his monitor.
The bottomline is that there were no extra checks and I wasn't denied boarding.
